# Equipotential lines / contour plot with singularities

Tags: plot, gnuplot, singular

I'm having trouble to create a plot with equipotential lines in gnuplot. Here is what I got so far:

```
f(x,y) = atan(y/(x+d))
d = 1.0

set view map
set isosamples 127, 127
unset surface 
set contour base
set cntrparam levels discrete pi/4.0

set xrange [ -2.0 : 2.0 ] noreverse nowriteback
set yrange [ -2.0 : 2.0 ] noreverse nowriteback

splot f(x,y) w l
```

It seems to work well, you can see the line with a gradient of 45°, except for the line at `x=-1`:

[image: my plot result]

I think it is because of the singularity in the argument of `atan`. In my final plot, there are even more similar singularities with similar lines not fitting into it.

Another thing: The lines should go through `[-1,0]`, but you can clearly see a hole in the line. How can I get a clean plot without holes and wrong lines?

1. How can i deal with this problem?
2. If not, maybe there is another way of plotting equipotential lines?
3. As last solution - what do you recommend, if gnuplot is not able to do this?

Thank you :)

Comment: you can try: `set samples 125` and `set isosamples 125, 125` to include singularity point. The line will be splitted to two parts

Comment: This doesn't work for me. But it looks like, for a first workaround, i can combine the `set samples` and `set isosamples` with a piecewise defined function like `f(x) = abs(x+d)>1e-2 ? atan(y/(x+d)) : NaN`. Then I still get some strange holes, but at least these artifact lines are gone... Still looking for a solution, not a workaround :)

Comment: I admit it is interesting, you can try to use `atan2()` instead of `atan()` or `arg(x+d +y*{0,1})` but it seems I missed something. Maybe it will be helpful for you. I am looking forward to see the solution.